# Доступ из делегата в Treeview

Tags: c#, делегаты, treeview

```
private Action<int> showMessage = delegate(int rubricId){
......
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
tn.Text = "Текст";
tn.Tag = "Тег";
treeView.Nodes.Add(tn);
}
```

Выдает ошибку **Ошибка  1   Инициализатор поля не может обращаться к нестатическому полю, методу или свойству "WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.catTree"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализаторы полей не могут работать с нестатическими полями. Вынесите инициализацию в конструктор вашего класса:

```
private Action<int> showMessage;

..
// в конструкторе Form1:
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    showMessage = (rubricId) => {
    //    ......
        TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
        tn.Text = "Текст";
        tn.Tag = "Тег";
        treeView.Nodes.Add(tn);
    }
}
```

Comment: А как для делегата Func быть? как для него лямбды юзать

Comment: @Radzhab654654 точно так же, как для `delegate`, с `return` в теле. просто убираете слово `delegate`, добавляете `=>` - это полностью эквивалентный аналог в этом случае. можно было оставить слово `delegate` в конструкторе, это просто вопрос личных предпочтений :)